# Can XMLRPC set show_on_front/page_on_front?

Tags: xml-rpc

Is it possible to set **show_on_front** and **page_on_front** via XMLRPC? They do not appear in the list returned from [wp.getOptions](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Options) and using wp.setOptions does not appear to change the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These options are not among the default writable `$blog_options`.

Here's one (untested) idea using the `xmlrpc_blog_options` filter to make the `show_on_front` option writeable:

```
/**
 * Add 'show_on_front' to the list of XML-RPC writeable options.
 */

add_filter( 'xmlrpc_blog_options', function( $blog_options ) 
{
    if( is_array( $blog_options ) )
    { 
        $blog_options['show_on_front'] = array(
            'desc'     => __( 'Show on front' ),
            'readonly' => false,
            'option'   => 'show_on_front'
        );
    }
    return $blog_options; 
});
```

and similar for the `page_on_front` option.